# Managed property as both a refiner and searchable

Tags: managed-metadata, enterprise-search, managed-property

I need to understand if it is possible to have two managed properties or even more for that matter that are mapped to one crawled property and be used as a refiner and another one as a searchable term, that can be returned in the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Also, you can have one that is both Queryable, Searchable and Refinable.